# Billing rule must be selected error

Tags: cpq

When I tried to mark the ordered(`SBQQ__Ordered__c`) checkbox from salesforce Quote(To generate a order) object, I receive the below error. Everything was fine until yesterday not sure what changes were made in the org.

**Dependencies:** Both salesforce CPQ and salesforce billing packages are installed in the org with multiple other dependencies(cloudcraze, docusign and tax integrations etc...).

**My Observation:** There are no relevant validation rules around the quote and order objects, also disabled custom triggers on these two objects. There is also a billing rule selected at a product level, which is used earlier and had no issues. I did enable debug logs to see if there are any exceptions thrown, all I find is the managed code but not any custom code exceptions. This happens for all the products in the org.

**Question:** What could be the reason for this error? What is the best way debug this error?

**Error:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Billing triggers are manually disabled at the package level as a workaround for supporting a different flow in the org. Once those triggers are re-enabled everything was working as expected. When these triggers are disable the twin fields won't propagate to copy the data. This error is a validation error from the package on orderItem that checks for the SBQQ_BillingType__C field. As the twin fields are not populated this error is thrown even though the billing rule is available at a product level